# Customizing UITabBarController by hiding the tabbar. Bad idea ?

Tags: ios, uikit

I'm investigating ways to customize the `UITabBarController`. The customization consists in custom images for each bar item and a "raised" central button item.

I know that Apple doesn't recommend subclassing the UITabBarController and I found some examples that handle this by writing a new component from scratch that mimics the default behavior.

But I'm feeling it's not worth dropping the functionality provided by default, as I only want to "skin" the component.

My idea is to hide the tabbar and place some custom buttons on top of the tabbar that will call the `tabbarcontroller.selectedIndex=<new_value>` when pressed.

Is this a bad idea ?

I don't see any downsides in this, but wanted to ask if there's any other simple way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not the worst idea in the world. I take R.A's point about user interface problems, but it seems pretty clear that from iOS 5 Apple are more than happy for people to change the look and feels of tabs - hence the new `UIAppearance` class and methods that let you specific custom tints, backgrounds, etc on tab bars and tab bar items.

And this is all very well and good on iOS 5, but if you want to have your nice fancy looking tab bar on iOS 4 you're going to need to come up with another approach. You could either code the whole tab-bar controller from scratch, or modify the existing one. Adding views on-top of the current tab-bar isn't the worst idea in the world. It's not *great*, but it's certainly one approach.

Of course, if you're able to target iOS 5 only you may want to look into the `UIAppearance` methods that the tab-bar makes available.

Comment: Yes, I like that iOS 5 has option to re-skin most controls, but I'm still targeting iOS 4 for now.

Answer (score 1):

Not a bad idea at all,you are not subclassing UITabBarController ,i.e. you are not violating terms & rules of Apple but creating your own buttons and adding them on view at the place of the original tabbar which gives the feeling of a customized tabbar so I think it is the best way to create custom tabbar without subclassing UITabBarController

Answer (score 0):

I think really its a bad idea. Because `Iphone` Users have to understand themselves by seeing that, it is a `TabBarItem` or `UIbutton`. For that purpose only, Apple is not allowing developers to `customize` it. If the user tapped a `UIButton`, then they will expect to do some action in next view, But If they click a TabBar Item, User will expect an action to perform in a same view. So there is a difference between them. Hope you understand.